# How do I create a password based cipher with Shiro?

Tags: java, security, shiro

I have created a method that lets me encrypt and decrypt an object with a password.  However, I am using Java's native encryption libraries but these are not very secure.  (For small changes in the object I am trying to serialize, I get 208 identical bytes out of a total of 243 encrypted bytes.)  I think [Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/cryptography-features.html) has alternatives, but I can't seem to find them (at least in 1.1.0 for password-based-encryption).  Here is my code for encrypting.  I inject the password value to the class and I'm leaving out any exception handling to keep things simpler:

```
public String encryptToString(Serializable object) {
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory =
            SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray());
    SecretKey secretKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
    PBEParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(SALT, ITERATIONS);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, paramSpec);
    // Serialize map
    final ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream =
            new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    CipherOutputStream cout =
            new CipherOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream, cipher);
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(cout);
    out.writeObject(object);
    out.close();
    cout.close();
    byteArrayOutputStream.close();
    return new String(
            Base64.encode(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()));
}
```

And my code for decrypting:

```
public Object decryptToObject(String encodedString) {
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory =
            SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray());
    SecretKey secretKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
    PBEParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(SALT, ITERATIONS);
    Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, paramSpec);
    final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream =
            new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(encodedString
                    .getBytes()));
    CipherInputStream cin =
            new CipherInputStream(byteArrayInputStream, decipher);
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(cin);
    Object result = in.readObject();
    in.close();
    cin.close();
    byteArrayInputStream.close();
    return result;
}
```